# Display all the possible numbers having its digits in ascending order

Tags: algorithm

Write a program that can display all the possible numbers in between given two numbers, having its digits in ascending order.

For Example:-

1. Input: 5000 to 6000

   ```
   Output: 5678 5679 5689 5789
   ```
2. Input: 90 to 124

   ```
   Output: 123 124
   ```

Brute force approach can make it count to all numbers and check of digits for each one of them. But I want approaches that can skip some numbers and can bring complexity lesser than O(n). Do any such solution(s) exists that can give better approach for this problem?

Comment: there are finite number of such numbers (less than `123456789`) therefore every correct algorithm is `O(1)`.

Comment: I feel a recursion coming

Comment: brute force in haskell: `[x | x <- [5000..6000], show x == nub (sort $ show x)]`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian For a range [a,b], the input size would be `log(a) + log(b-a)` (the minimum number and the distance between them). Iterating over `b-a` numbers would be exponential for all but very small ranges, not O(1).

Comment: @chepner: 1. Input size is `n=b-a` where `n` is representable in `O(1)` machine words 2. Every algorithm that considers only valid numbers would look at no more than `123456789` of them (a rather small number for modern computers). It provides the hard upper limit on number of necessary steps regardless of `n` hence `O(1)` time complexity.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You can't use machine-specific parameters like memory size to define your input encoding. That violates the assumption of platform independence when describing an algorithm's run-time, which is solely a function of its input size, not the underlying hardware that implements it. The input size to this problem is indeed O(lg n) , and the algorithm in the worst case needs to consider an exponential number of values.

Comment: @chepner: the machine is still abstract. Read about [models of computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation), *the key point to understand that there could be more than one*, and you could specify it explicitly, and having `n` be representable in `O(1)` machine words is convient because many primitive operations have intuitively obvious `O(1)` time complexities in this case e.g., a comparison based sort is `O(n * log n)` in this model.

Comment: I feel that even Brute force will be a an O(n) solution. n (numbers) * k (digits of a number), and we know the number k is finite. so O(n)*k is still O(n). since k will always be finite.

Comment: @chepner: May be it could be silly to you. But can you please make me understand how have you calculated problem's input size as O(logn). What does log(a) + log(b-a) signifies? And how come "Iterating over b-a numbers would be exponential". When input_size is n=(b-a), iteration over 'n' numbers sould be 'n' only. :P

Comment: @akshit See my answer. Put (too) simply, there are 10 1-digit numbers, 100 2-digit numbers, 1000 3-digit numbers, etc. The number of values you need to check grows exponentially with the number of digits needed to represent the upper bound.

Comment: @chepner Thank U. This one makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

I offer a solution in Python.  It is efficient as it considers only the relevant numbers.  The basic idea is to count upwards, but handle overflow somewhat differently.  While we normally set overflowing digits to 0, here we set them to the previous digit +1.  Please check the inline comments for further details.  You can play with it here: http://ideone.com/ePvVsQ

```
def ascending( na, nb ):
    assert nb>=na
    # split each number into a list of digits
    a = list( int(x) for x in str(na))
    b = list( int(x) for x in str(nb))

    d = len(b) - len(a)

    # if both numbers have different length add leading zeros 
    if d>0:
        a = [0]*d + a  # add leading zeros
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    n = len(a)


    # check if the initial value has increasing digits as required,
    # and fix if necessary
    for x in range(d+1, n):
        if a[x] <= a[x-1]:
            for y in range(x, n):
                a[y] = a[y-1] + 1
            break

    res = [] # result set

    while a<=b:
        # if we found a value and add it to the result list
        # turn the list of digits back into an integer
        if max(a) < 10:
            res.append( int( ''.join( str(k) for k in a ) ) )

        # in order to increase the number we look for the
        # least significant digit that can be increased
        for x in range( n-1, -1, -1): # count down from n-1 to 0
            if a[x] < 10+x-n:
                break
        # digit x is to be increased
        a[x] += 1
        # all subsequent digits must be increased accordingly
        for y in range( x+1, n ):
            a[y] = a[y-1] + 1

    return res

print( ascending( 5000, 9000 ) )
```

Comment: Good idea. Seems like it is simpler than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like task from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/). Here is the solution in C++. It is not short, but it is straightforward and effective. Oh, and hey, it uses [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

```
// Higher order digits at the back
typedef std::vector<int> Digits;

// Extract decimal digits of a number
Digits ExtractDigits(int n)
{
  Digits digits;

  while (n > 0)
  {
    digits.push_back(n % 10);
    n /= 10;
  }

  if (digits.empty())
  {
    digits.push_back(0);
  }

  return digits;
}

// Main function
void PrintNumsRec(
  const Digits& minDigits,  // digits of the min value
  const Digits& maxDigits,  // digits of the max value
  Digits& digits,  // digits of current value
  int pos,         // current digits with index greater than pos are already filled
  bool minEq,      // currently filled digits are the same as of min value
  bool maxEq)      // currently filled digits are the same as of max value
{
  if (pos < 0)
  {
    // Print current value. Handle leading zeros by yourself, if need
    for (auto pDigit = digits.rbegin(); pDigit != digits.rend(); ++pDigit)
    {
      if (*pDigit >= 0)
      {
        std::cout << *pDigit;
      }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  // Compute iteration boundaries for current position
  int first = minEq ? minDigits[pos] : 0;
  int last = maxEq ? maxDigits[pos] : 9;

  // The last filled digit
  int prev = digits[pos + 1];

  // Make sure generated number has increasing digits
  int firstInc = std::max(first, prev + 1);

  // Iterate through possible cases for current digit
  for (int d = firstInc; d <= last; ++d)
  {
    digits[pos] = d;

    if (d == 0 && prev == -1)
    {
      // Mark leading zeros with -1
      digits[pos] = -1;
    }

    PrintNumsRec(minDigits, maxDigits, digits, pos - 1, minEq && (d == first), maxEq && (d == last));
  }
}

// High-level function
void PrintNums(int min, int max)
{
  auto minDigits = ExtractDigits(min);
  auto maxDigits = ExtractDigits(max);

  // Make digits array of the same size
  while (minDigits.size() < maxDigits.size())
  {
    minDigits.push_back(0);
  }

  Digits digits(minDigits.size());

  int pos = digits.size() - 1;

  // Placeholder for leading zero
  digits.push_back(-1);

  PrintNumsRec(minDigits, maxDigits, digits, pos, true, true);
}

void main()
{
  PrintNums(53, 297);
}
```

It uses recursion to handle arbitrary amount of digits, but it is essentially the same as the nested loops approach. Here is the output for `(53, 297)`:

```
056
057
058
059
067
068
069
078
079
089
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
134
135
136
137
138
139
145
146
147
148
149
156
157
158
159
167
168
169
178
179
189
234
235
236
237
238
239
245
246
247
248
249
256
257
258
259
267
268
269
278
279
289
```

Much more interesting problem would be to count all these numbers without explicitly computing it. One would use dynamic programming for that.

Comment: Since the question didn't ask for C++, you may want to add a high-level description or pseudo-code of the proposed solution in addition to / instead of the actual code, especially given that it's not short.

Comment: `PrintNums( 216, 237 );` -> 236 237 .  It's missing 234 and 235.

Comment: @pentadecagon You are right, fixed issue with `first` variable.

Comment: `PrintNums( 6, 100 );` -> misses 7, 8, 9

Comment: @pentadecagon I'm impressed how you thoroughly check other's ugly code :) The problem turned out to be not so trivial as it seemed. I updated the code, but now it looks really too long.

Comment: Actually, I didn't take a single look at your code.  I just was thinking about a solution myself so I already considered all the corner cases, and just threw them at your program :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is only a very limited number of numbers which can match your definition (with 9 digits max) and these can be generated very fast. But if you really need speed, just cache the tree or the generated list and do a lookup when you need your result.

```s
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace so_ascending_digits
{
  class Program
  {
    class Node
    {
        int digit;
        int value;
        List<Node> children;

        public Node(int val = 0, int dig = 0)
        {
            digit = dig;
            value = (val * 10) + digit;
            children = new List<Node>();
            for (int i = digit + 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                children.Add(new Node(value, i));
            }
        }

        public void Collect(ref List<int> collection, int min = 0, int max = Int16.MaxValue)
        {
            if ((value >= min) && (value <= max)) collection.Add(value);
            foreach (Node n in children) if (value * 10 < max) n.Collect(ref collection, min, max);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node root = new Node();
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        root.Collect(ref numbers, 5000, 6000);
        numbers.Sort();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", numbers));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Why the brute force algorithm may be very inefficient.

One efficient way of encoding the input is to provide two numbers: the lower end of the range, *a*, and the number of values in the range, *b-a-1*. This can be encoded in O(lg *a* + lg (*b* - *a*)) bits, since the number of bits needed to represent a number in base-2 is roughly equal to the base-2 logarithm of the number. We can simplify this to O(lg *b*), because intuitively if *b* - *a* is small, then *a* = O(*b*), and if *b* - *a* is large, then *b* - *a* = O(*b*). Either way, the total input size is O(2 lg *b*) = O(lg *b*).

Now the brute force algorithm just checks each number from *a* to *b*, and outputs the numbers whose digits in base 10 are in increasing order. There are *b* - *a* + 1 possible numbers in that range. However, when you represent this in terms of the input size, you find that *b* - *a* + 1 = 2<sup>lg (*b* - *a* + 1)</sup> = 2<sup>O(lg *b*)</sup> for a large enough interval.

This means that for an input size *n* = O(lg *b*), you may need to check in the worst case O(2 <sup>*n*</sup>) values.

### A better algorithm

Instead of checking every possible number in the interval, you can simply generate the valid numbers directly. Here's a rough overview of how. A number *n* can be thought of as a sequence of digits *n*<sub>1</sub> ... *n*<sub>k</sub>, where *k* is again roughly log<sub>10</sub> *n*.

For *a* and a four-digit number *b*, the iteration would look something like

```
for w in a1 .. 9:
  for x in w+1 .. 9:
    for y in x+1 .. 9:
      for x in y+1 .. 9:
         m = 1000 * w + 100 * x + 10 * y + w
         if m < a:
            next
         if m > b:
            exit
         output w ++ x ++ y ++ z  (++ is just string concatenation)
```

where *a*<sub>1</sub> can be considered 0 if *a* has fewer digits than *b*.

For larger numbers, you can imagine just adding more nested for loops. In general, if *b* has *d* digits, you need *d* = O(lg *b*) loops, each of which iterates at most 10 times.  The running time is thus O(10 lg *b*) = O(lg *b*) , which is a far better than the O(2<sup>lg *b*</sup>) running time you get by checking if every number is sorted or not.

---

One other detail that I have glossed over, which actually *does* affect the running time. As written, the algorithm needs to consider the time it takes to generate `m`. Without going into the details, you could assume that this adds at worst a factor of O(lg *b*) to the running time, resulting in an O(lg<sup>2</sup> *b*) algorithm. However, using a little extra space at the top of each for loop to store partial products would save lots of redundant multiplication, allowing us to preserve the originally stated O(lg *b*) running time.

Comment: I don't agree with the calculation you made to calculate the number of bits needed to represent the problem size. See in log(a) + log(b-a) expression; log(a) gives the number of bits needed to represent value 'a' but for such (b-a) number of values, we will need atmost '(b-a)logb' bits. Hence the final expression should be like O(loga + (b-a)logb) and thus further expressions changes accordingly.

Comment: The approach in pseudo code you mentioned is indeed a good one but problem with this one is that it will require a lot of twist & tweaks in actual code if number ranges consist different order of digits. e.g. (80,125) output numbers will be 89, 123, 124. Numbers having no. of digits as 2 and 3. So, for a large given range like (80, 1234) separate loops will be required corresponding to number of digits we have. In this case a loop to generate 2 digit numbers only with other loops considering 3 and 4 number of digits.

Comment: You don't actually specify all *b* - *a* numbers in the range in the input. You only specify two numbers that completely *describe* the range, and let the algorithm generate the range for you. For the purposes of this algorithm, you can assume that all numbers have the same number of digits by using leading zeros when necessary: 080 - 125.

Comment: I do need to make one simply change to the algorithm to avoid printing numbers less than *a*, though.

Comment: But there algorithm is actually working on input size from (a,b) not just 'a' and 'b'. Then, how can we escape it in running time?

Comment: why do u want to print numbers less than 'a'? when it asks numbers for only in (a,b) range. To generate numbers like 0089 and so... Many changes are required in your code because it violates x=w+1 property.

Comment: The `if m < a: next` part that I added skips numbers less than *a*.

Comment: Ohh sorry didn't notice that actively :P

Answer (score 0):

One way (pseudo-code):

```
for (digit3 = '5'; digit3 <= '6'; digit3++)
  for (digit2 = digit3+1; digit2 <= '9'; digit2++)
    for (digit1 = digit2+1; digit1 <= '9'; digit1++)
      for (digit0 = digit1+1; digit0 <= '9'; digit0++)
        output = digit3 + digit2 + digit1 + digit0; // concatenation
```

Comment: How will it handle 572,600? How will you handle variable length input? (888,9999999)?

Comment: Also, the time complexity of your algorithm is O(10^#digits). It is simpler to just go through all numbers in the relevant range and print them if they are in correct order - in the same time complexity.

Comment: `the time complexity of your algorithm is O(10^#digits)` - no, it isn't.

Comment: @amit: This was just an illustration of the principle.

Comment: Care to share you complexity analysis? Please make assumption of a variant of the problem where the numbers are not strictly increasing (i.e. 1111 is also valid, for example) - this makes the problem not bounded by size with a very little changes needed for your algorithm.

Comment: The time complexity is really O(#digits), as I explain in my answer. Allowing non-decreasing outputs, in addition to strictly increasing outputs, does not affect the complexity.